# EntityFramework.Core 2.0 preview - OnConfiguring method not called

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm testing `EF core 2.0` preview. But when I try to get a new instance of `DbContext` as I do usually with `EF core 1.1.2`, `OnConfiguring` method is not called:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    DatabasesType database_type;
    string URI;

    public DbSet<User> user;

    public DatabaseContext(DatabasesType database_type, string URI) : base()
    {
        this.database_type = database_type;
        this.URI = URI;            
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        switch (database_type)
        {
            case DatabasesType.MySQL:
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(URI); break;
            case DatabasesType.SQLite:
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(URI); break;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What is happening? Someone with similar error?

Thank you!

Comment: Finally i found the mistake: I have to set get; set; auto-property to user